# Working with multipart/form-data in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, content-type

I've a lambda function that is invoked from AWS API Gateway.

The lambda is receiving an image as a *multipart/form-data* and then the lambda needs to add some extra headers and pass that image to another external service using *multipart/form-data* too.

Right now, my service is doing this:

```js
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const https = require('https');
const request = require('request');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://external-service/image-storage',
        port: 443,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        formData: {
            username: "67a43djte5s4cb54mnasbds23",
            secret: "47938hjfsdhjfdfdfs",
            photo: \\ I want to put here the image received in the event
        }
    };

    request(options, function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(body);
    });
}
```

In the `photo` parameter I've tried to put `event.body` but it's not working, as the external service gives me an "invalid request" (I've tried the external service with postman and it's working properly).

So I think that the problem is on the lambda.

When I print in the console the content of the `event.body` this is the output:

```
2020-04-02T13:17:27.478Z    0c03qsrf-78a2-2356-b9b0-0fd76fb367712   INFO    ----------------------------027326659651005153655343
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="MyImage.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
����JFIF��C...
```

Do I need to make any additional transformation to the body?

Thanks,

Comment: Ran into the same challenge, see https://dev.to/mhausenblas/a-lesson-learned-in-going-serverless-1ko8 for how I went about it …

Comment: thanks @MichaelHausenblas I found your question in SO a couple hours ago during the researching stage; unfortunately I cannot use the pre-signed urls due other restrictions in the frontend (at least for now) thanks!! great post btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case that someone arrives here having the same question that I had yesterday, the best approach is to follow the recommendation from [Michael Hausenblas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396567/michael-hausenblas) (see his comment under my question) and use S3 and pre-signed urls.

However, due some limitations in my front-end I couldn't took that approach.

Finally I had to replace the API input from *multipart/form-data* content-type to *application/json* and send the image enconded in base64 in a JSON object from my frontend to my lambda. And then from the lambda build the multipart object for the external service:

```js
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const request = require('request');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    let json_body = JSON.parse(event.body)
    var base64image = json_body.image;
    base64image = base64image.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '');


    request({
        url: 'https://external-service/image-storage',
        method: 'POST',
        formData: {
          'username': '67a43djte5s4cb54mnasbds23',
          'secret': '47938hjfsdhjfdfdfs',
          'image': {
            value: Buffer.from(base64image, 'base64'),
            options: {
              filename: 'photo1.jpg',
              contentType: 'image/jpeg'
            }
          }
        }
      }, function (err,resp,body){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error");
        }else{
            console.log("Response" + body);
        }
    });   
}
```

As I said, I would recommend to follow the pre-signed urls approach but I offer this alternative in case you also have limitations on your front-end.